# scrollIntoView first found element within loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm experimenting with data-, and ran into a problem that I can't solve at the moment.

I'm trying to scrollIntoView, e.g.: [0] , for the first 'clients[i]':

```
function search() {
searchTerm = document.getElementById("searchInput").value;
clients = document.getElementsByClassName("client");

for (var i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
    find = clients[i].getAttribute("data-search-firstname");
    if (searchTerm === find) {
        console.log("Found: " + find);
        selClient(clients[i]);
        clients[i].scrollIntoView(); // not sure where to put [0] without an error
    }
}

}
```

Thanks a ton!

EDIT:

For example, if I have multiple of the same 'clients[i]', I want the first client to scrollIntoView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to identify if `i` is the first result

```
function search() {
    searchTerm = document.getElementById("searchInput").value;
    clients = document.getElementsByClassName("client");

    for (var i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
        find = clients[i].getAttribute("data-search-firstname");
        if (searchTerm === find) {
            console.log("Found: " + find);
            selClient(clients[i]);
            if (i === 0) {
                clients[i].scrollIntoView();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Or in your case it looks like you only want it scrolling to the first result in loop where `searchterm === find` so you might want to do this:

```
function search() {
    searchTerm = document.getElementById("searchInput").value;
    clients = document.getElementsByClassName("client");

    var scrolled = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
        find = clients[i].getAttribute("data-search-firstname");
        if (searchTerm === find) {
            console.log("Found: " + find);
            selClient(clients[i]);
            if (!scrolled) {
                clients[i].scrollIntoView();
                scrolled = true;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried both methods, the first one works really well. Thanks!